# Encoding special characters SQL to R and back

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, encoding, dbi

I have a problem passing data from R to SQL and then reading it back
The original data is from some excel files and have the following word: `Průmyslový`

Using `latin1` for encoding depreciates the u within the word `Prumyslový`

Using `latin2` for encoding changes the accent of the u `Prùmyslový`

Which encoding could i use?
I am using an MS SQL 2016 server and the package `DBI` and usually the following code where the word is part of the data frame that I am writing to the server.

I am not using `UTF-8` because then `öffentlicher` becomes `Ã¶ffentlicher`

```
DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "SQL Server",
                      Server = "DBABMZ0006", 
                      Database = "EA_DB",
                      encoding = "latin1")

DBI::dbWriteTable(con,
                  Tabelle,
                  df_temp,
                  append=TRUE)

df_test<-DBI::dbReadTable(con,
                          Tabelle)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latin1 Encoding does not support many special characters, especially not the "€" sign, **but** it is possible to save the "€" sign in columns of VARCHAR type with Latin1 database collations, here the Backgrounds and the solution for your `Ã¶`, `ů` and other encoding problems:

Our Microsoft SQL Database is set to "Latin1_General_CI_AS" collation, this use "iso_1" character set. In short "iso_1" means “ISO-8859-1” but is “Windows-1252” (CP1252). Mislabeled by Microsoft [Details here](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2021/05/21/sql-server-collations-what-does-cp1-mean-in-sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as/).

In our Rprofile.site config file of our R installations, we set the encoding with `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` for each R Session to "UTF-8" as default.

To check which encoding your R sessions are using, execute `getOption("encoding")` command. If you are using Windows and "native.enc" is returned, then I assume that "Windows-1252" encoding used (Encoding of your operating system).

We use **VARCHAR** Type (= 8-bit codepage) in columns of our tables, with setting `encoding = "CP1252"` (Encoding of SQL database) our problems are gone:

```
 DBI = {
      dbconnection <- DBI::dbConnect(
        drv = odbc::odbc(),
        Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
        Server = instance,
        Database = database,
        # Encoding of SQL-Server, not latin1(!)
        encoding = "CP1252", 
        # Encoding of R sessions, Windows R default is "CP1252" (Windows-1252)
        clientcharset = "UTF-8" 
      )
    }
```

Also you can try to set the `clientcharset` property to the encoding of your R sessions.

"ů" not exist in Windows-1252 encoding. If you use **NVARCHAR** columns (=Unicode) and if you set then `encoding` to UTF-16 then you can also save the character "ů".

Comment: thx for this very detailed answers. Unfortunately this is not a currenc problem for me anymore. Ill just mark yours as accepted as it just sounds very good.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding utf-8, it should work.

```
DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "SQL Server",
                      Server = "DBABMZ0006", 
                      Database = "EA_DB",
                      encoding = "UTF-8")
```

[Here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm) is list of character in this encoding.

Comment: I am explicitly using `latin1` because using `UTF-8` displayed all other german special characters as ?

Comment: what about ASCII??

Comment: `encoding = "ASCII"` is worse then several words just become NA